# value: UnpackNestedValue<PathValue<T, Path<T>>>

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form and Im getting this error `value: UnpackNestedValue<PathValue<T, Path<T>>>` whenever I pass the value as a prop.

Here is my switch button component:

```
type Props<T> = {
  height: number
} & UseControllerProps<T> &
  InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>

function SwitchButton<T>(props: Props<T>) {
  const {
    field: { onChange, value },
  } = useController(props)

  return (
    <Switch height={props.height}>
      <input type='checkbox' checked={value} onChange={onChange} />
      <Slider height={props.height}></Slider>
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

In the above code Im getting an error in checked attribute: `Type 'UnpackNestedValue<PathValue<T, Path<T>>>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.`

This is my form:

```
const defaultValues = {
  title: '',
  project: {
    id: '',
    title: ''
    },
  isOpen: false,
  ...
  }

const { handleSubmit, control, setError, watch } =
  useForm<FormType>({
    defaultValues,
  })

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>
  <SwitchButton<FormType>
    name='isOpen'
    height={20}
    control={control}
  />
  ...
</form>
```

```
import { NestedValue } from 'react-hook-form'

type FormType = {
  title: string
  project: NestedValue<{
    id: string
    title: string
  }>
  isOpen: boolean
  ...
}
```

Im getting the same error in all other form components, does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you

Comment: Can you share a codesadbox with your issue please?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/value-unpacknestedvalue-pathvalue-t-path-t-kv5go?file=/src/App.tsx
Sandbox is not complaining about that type issue even though I have the same tsconfig and react-hook-form version